# How do I overwrite one of my theme's JavaScript functions in WordPress?

Tags: javascript, wordpress, wordpress-theming

I'm working with a WordPress theme that outputs the site through a one-pager JS application, sitting in theme-folder/frontend/assets/js/.

I managed to make the changes I wanted to the relevant JS file while editing the file directly. Now I'm looking to see how I assure the theme is still updatable and don't see the need for a child theme here.

Instead of editing the JS file directly, I thought I could use a plugin like Code Snippets and overwrite the function. So the JS wouldn't be replaced during a theme update. I just have no idea how to tackle this this…

The function in the application.js:

function(e, t, n) { … },

The Code Snippet plugin suggests as a JS example:

add_action( 'wp_head', function () { ?>

```
</script>
```

I can also set a priority, which comes with a value of 10. If I overwrite with a higher priority and the function doesn't change fundamentally, I should be able to go with updates, right?

Comment: Why are you against a child theme? If you just create a child theme and put only the javascript file you edited in the child theme youre good to go

Comment: The thing is that most of the theme's features run in this single js file. Meaning I would need to update the file manually each time a theme update comes out. That's why I'm trying to figure out how to overwrite or replace that one function. Maybe a child theme would do the same thing but if it is only that one function I thought a plugin is simply easier.

Comment: Your code snippet should work. I would just create a simple one file plugin or function in functions.php and enqueue it  https://codex.wordpress.org/Plugin_API/Action_Reference/wp_enqueue_scripts